# What/How can I optimize for my API?

Tags: api, design-patterns, architecture

This is more of an architectural question.

I am designing an API (lets call it API 1) for a mobile app that will query my API for new articles. I will call another API (lets call it API 2) that returns Raw news feed to me.

***You ask why is API 1 needed at all?*** Well, it will do lot of optimization like curate edition specific news, format it in such a way that it is easier and light for the mobile to assimilate the feed.

So API 2 return 1000+ feeds to me and then based on my curation lets say I have 500 feeds to send using API 1. Now with caching and all it is all good for my backend. The problem is with the mobile devices (especially older ones). They start breaking a sweat with huge responses (270kb after Gzip).

My solution: **Pagination:**

I can split the 500 news articles to 5*100 articles. The app can request for page 1,2,3,4 and 5. ***Potential cons:*** When API 1 sends fresh articles the split of 5*100 is disturbed. For instance see the news feed on mobile device:

Article 1,

Article 2,

..

Article 99,

Article 100

----Page ended----

Article 101,

Article 102,

***Now after API 1 refreshes feed:***

**New Article 1,**

**New Article 2,**

Article 1,

Article 2,

..

----Page ended----

Article 99 (duplicate),

Article 100 (duplicate)

Article 101,

Article 102,

What are the best practices for such a problem?

**EDIT**
To get a better mental picture of the problem, Think of an app similar to Apple news or Google newstand and somewhat similar to Twitter and facebook feeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign a unique id to each article, say, a GUID, and expose those to the UI along with the articles themselves. Then the UI's requests would look like "hey API 1, give me the next 100 articles after the article #id". Then the API 1 endpoint would look for the specified #id in the cached feed and retrieve the next 100 articles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But no, that is not what I want. Yes there are pages, but those pages are in the context of my API 1 response. The app  UI will be a continuous scrolling feed. The newest articles will only be shown during a pull to refresh event etc.

Comment: And regarding the "don't add the newly pulled articles to the displayed list until the first page is requested". I like that approach, however, the API 2 response is cached and it gets updated every 5 minutes and it will be counter-intuitive to store that volatile a data in memory. So if new articles are pulled, I just need to maintain a context to fetch the next few articles based on my last pull.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. I honestly still can't build a consistent mental model of the problem, so you might want to extend the problem description with details on how the interaction between the UI, API 1, and API 2 is happening.

Comment: Thanks! Rewritten the answer hoping to have a better understanding of the problem this time.